# How to debug Javascript test files in the browser using gulp test and karma

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, debugging, jasmine, gulp-karma

I wrote a javascript test using the jasmine framework, and I run my tests using with "gulp test". Below is my test.js

```
gulp.task('test', function(done) {
  new Karma({
    configFile: __dirname + '/../../karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: false
  }, done).start();
});
```

My question is what do i have to do so that i can debug my test file? I want to be able to walk through the test file line by line?
Is there any property in karma.conf.js that i have to manipulate to be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good start changing `singleRun` to false.

Put a `debugger` in where you want it to stop.

Then run `gulp test` to get the browser open.

Open Chrome Dev Tool.

Run again, it should stop at the debugger.